# How to encode/decode Timestamp for json in circe?

Tags: json, scala, slick-3.0, circe

While using circe in slick to get data in json,I could fetch data having no date`(Timestamp/DateTime)` fields in Entities. But when I use `Timestamp` fields in Entities, the error is thrown:

```
[error] /var/www/html/scala-api/src/main/scala/oc/api/http/routes/TestApi.scala:40: could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[Seq[oc.api.models.UserEntity]]
[error]             auth => complete(userDao.getAll().map(_.asJson))
```

Here is the code, I used for Slick Entities and using CIRCE for json encoding.

**BaseTable:**

```
abstract class BaseTable[T](tag: Tag, name: String) extends Table[T](tag, name) {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def createdAt = column[Timestamp]("created_at")
  def updatedAt = column[Timestamp]("updated_at")
  def deletedAt = column[Timestamp]("deleted_at")
}
```

**BaseEntity:**

```
trait BaseEntity {
  val id : Long
  def isValid : Boolean = true
}
```

**UserEntity: createdAt generates encoder error**

```
case class UserEntity(id: Long, email: String, password: String, createdAt: Timestamp) extends BaseEntity
```

**UserEntity: This works perfectly**

```
case class UserEntity(id: Long, email: String, password: String) extends BaseEntity
```

**UserTable(Slick):**

```
object UserTables {

  class UserTable(tag : Tag) extends BaseTable[UserEntity](tag, "users") {
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def password = column[String]("password")
    def * = (id, name, password) <> (UserEntity.tupled, UserEntity.unapply)
  }

  implicit val accountsTableQ : TableQuery[UserTable] = TableQuery[UserTable]
}
```

Am I missing something in the code? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use a custom encoder and decoder to your code, something like that :

```
  implicit val TimestampFormat : Encoder[Timestamp] with Decoder[Timestamp] = new Encoder[Timestamp] with Decoder[Timestamp] {
    override def apply(a: Timestamp): Json = Encoder.encodeLong.apply(a.getTime)

    override def apply(c: HCursor): Result[Timestamp] = Decoder.decodeLong.map(s => new Timestamp(s)).apply(c)
  }
```

Put this val in whatever code needs to encode/decode timestamps. For example, you can put it in an object, and import the object where needed.

Comment: I tried to add n Table as
object UserTables {
  class UserTable(tag : Tag) extends BaseTable[UserEntity](tag, "users") {
    def updated_at = column[Option[String]]("updated_at")
    def * = (..., updated_at) <> (...)
  }
 implicit val TimestampFormat : Encoder[Timestamp] with Decoder[Timestamp] = new Encoder[Timestamp] with Decoder[Timestamp] {
    override def apply(a: Timestamp): Json = Encoder.encodeLong.apply(a.getTime)

    override def apply(c: HCursor): Result[Timestamp] = Decoder.decodeLong.map(s => new Timestamp(s)).apply(c)
  }
}

But got encoder error as before

Comment: You have to put the val in scope of where the encoding/decoding is actually done (so, probably somewhere near http related code ?), not in the sql classes !

Comment: While decoding, how can I use DateTimeFormat i.e. Y-m-d H:i:s to decode instead of decodeLong

Comment: You can use decodeString.map(s => function(s)) where function should be a function to transform the String you have in Timestamp (using DateTimeFormat in the process I suppose).

Comment: Cheers! 

decodeString.map( s => new Timestamp(timestampFormatter.parse(s).getTime)).apply(c) worked